# como realizar un programa de bingo en pseint

Tags: pseint

Elaborar un programa en pseint que simule un sistema de calculadora numérica. El cual consiste
en lo siguiente:
El juego
El juego sólo permite jugadores registrados. Antes de jugar, un jugador debe ingresar su nombre,
edad, Nick (nombre con el que se conocerá en el juego) y sexo. Una vez registrado, el jugador
tiene un tablero aleatoriamente. En este BINGO, el tablero se forma teniendo en la cuenta que
cada letra tiene cinco números que se eligen entre quince opciones de números. En otras
palabras, la letra B tiene cinco números que se eligen (sin repetir) entre el 1 y el 15. La letra I
tiene otros cinco números que se eligen entre el 16 y el 30. La letra N tiene otros cinco (no cuatro
como el juego original) que se eligen entre el 31 y el 45. La letra G otros cinco que se eligen entre
el 46 y el 60. Y la letra O otros cinco entre el 61 y el 75.
A continuación, se presenta un ejemplo de tablero:

B I N G O
1 16 31 46 61
4 20 32 50 75
7 22 33 52 70
11 29 34 47 64
13 17 35 48 65

Una vez el usuario decide jugar, el Bingo comienza a generar números aleatorios entre 1 y 75
(sin repetirlos), siempre mostrándolos con la letra que corresponde. El programa debe ir
mostrando el tablero con los que esté jugando un usuario y mostrar el número que sale.
Allí el jugador debería decir si ingresa el número del tablero en que se encuentra el número en
que salió en el Bingo o una ‘x’ en caso de no tenerlo.
Después de esto, el programa le mostraría al usuario el tablero donde él dijo que estaba el
número tapados por una ‘x’:

B I N G O
1 16 31 46 61
4 20 32 50 75
7 22 33 52 70
11 29 34 47 64
x 17 35 48 65

En caso de que el jugador digite 1 se tapará en el tablero que el usuario dijo. Y en caso de que
el usuario digite un número de tablero distinto no hace nada y sigue con el siguiente número
aleatorio, simplemente no tapará ningún número en ese tablero, pero le avisará al usuario que
se equivocó.
El jugador juega hasta que desee o hasta que se acaben los números. Para salir debe digitar ‘s’.
2
Cuando el usuario termina el juego, sin importar si fue por retiro o porque se acabaron todos los
números del BINGO, se calcula el puntaje obtenido hasta ese momento, donde cada número de
cada letra tendrán un valor, B = 2, I = 4, N = 6, G = 8 y O = 10, sumando el total y mandando dicho
puntaje.

Comment: Hola Rey, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.